# How to distinguish when the preposition "BY" refers to the object previously or the whole sentence afterwards

Tags: prepositions

Example: The behavior of a resource is determined **by**
which HTTP method the resource is responding to.

Is the part "which HTTP method the resource is responding to" the object of **by**?
But it seems to me also understandable that the **which** in **by which** refers to the part "The behavior of a resource".

Comment: *which ... to* is a *free relative* clause which has no referent, not an ordinary relative clause (with pied-piping, *by ... to*) bound to a prior referent. You could write this in active voice as "Which HTTP method the resource is responding to determines the behavior of a resource."

Comment: @StoneyB, thank you so much for your explanation. It's still hard for a non-English speaker to find a fast way to distinguish the role of which.

Comment: Look at the *by*: in this context it's not going to be spatial, so it designates the Agent of a passive construction. That means it doesn't belong with "responding" but with "determined".

Comment: Right; a pied-piped relative pronoun _by which_ is very common, but it would follow  a noun. This one follows a passive verb construction, and the string _by which_ is not a constituent; the object of _by_, as suggested, is the entire embedded question clause _which method it is responding to_. Note that the final _to_ is stranded at the end of the clause by the movement of its object _which_ the front of the clause by Wh-Question Formation, which is normal; but note also that it can't be pied-piped here, which is not: _*..is determined by to which method it is responding_ is ungrammatical.

Comment: +1 StoneyB and John Lawler: your explanation is really helpful. Now I understand much better. I think the best way of learning pied-piped relative pronoun is understand the whole sentence without caring about any grammar. But I haven't reached that level yet, I can only learn from the grammar. Thank you guys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your analysis seems essentially correct. 'By' is a preposition and the prepositional phrase is adverbial, modifying "is determined" by telling *how* something is done.

The object of the preposition is a dependent noun clause with relative pronoun 'which'.  This particular clause "which HTTP method the resource is responding to" is a bit convoluted, but rearranges as an independent clause as follows:

> The resource is responding to [that] HTTP method.

BBC World Service has a [discussion here of preposition + relative pronoun constructs](http://www.bbc.co.uk/worldservice/learningenglish/grammar/learnit/learnitv286.shtml).